# Why is document.getElementById().setAttribute not working correctly in Chrome and IE?

Tags: javascript, function, pdf, object, setattribute

I am using the following function:

`function pdfChanger(location){
document.getElementById("pdf").setAttribute("data",location);
}`

which is called here:

```
<a href="javascript:pdfChanger('documents/SecurityDocs/sample.pdf')">test1</a><br/>
```

and is designed to change the pdf file displayed in this object:

```
<object id="pdf" data="documents/sample2.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&page=1&view=FitHtop" 
                    type="application/pdf"></object>
```

In firefox clicking on the link which evokes this function changes the pdf object correctly. In chrome, however, you have to click on the pdf after you have clicked the link, in order to correctly display the changed pdf. In IE the pdf does not change at all. Why is this happening and what can I do to make this function work uniformly in all browsers?

Comment: Does changing the attribute make any difference? Say to "data-path" or something along those lines. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute mentions some reserved words, and while they only mention "value", it might be good to rule that out.

Answer (score 0):

Setting attribute value does not guarantee re-rendering of a html element.

if we change width or height of img tag, we always see the image re-rendered.

How about if we change id of an img tag, does browser need to re-render the image? I don't think so, but some browser might.

'data' attribute of object tag can be think as differently from browser to browser from the rendering point of view. it is regarded as 'data' or 'source url'.

To guarantee the rendering of the element, you had better to re-write the whole element. You can create/add element or use innerHTML. For example,

```
document.getElementById('object_div').innerHTML='<object id="pdf" ...></object>'
```